# Please help me in understanding this piece of code

Tags: r, function

I have just started learning R from Datacamp and got stuck at the following function:

```
below_zero <- function(x) {
    return(x[x < 0])
}
```

Website says that this function does the following:

> We already created a function, below_zero(), that takes a vector of
> numerical values and returns a vector that only contains the values
> that are strictly below zero.

This function will be applied to this list called "temp":

> [[1]] [1]  3  7  9  6 -1
>
> [[2]] [1]  6  9 12 13  5
>
> [[3]] [1]  4  8  3 -1 -3
>
> [[4]] [1]  1  4  7  2 -2
>
> [[5]] [1] 5 7 9 4 2
>
> [[6]] [1] -3  5  8  9  4
>
> [[7]] [1] 3 6 9 4 1

But, I'm not really able to understand this part in particular:

> (x[x < 0])

If for e.g., `x[1]` returns the 1st element in the vector then what exactly is `[x < 0]` doing?

Is `x < 0` returning a logical statement or really a number?

Please explain as to what this piece of code is doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you try out `x < 0`  for the an example vector `x <- c(-3,-1,1,2)` you will get the result of  `TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE` since R checks every value of `x` if it is less than 0. Since the result is a logical vector you can use that as selector for `x`.
A full example:

```
x <- c(-3,-1,1,2) # input
y <- x < 0 # logical vector
x[y] # filter
```

So, you have two options of selection:

1. by index: as you mentioned with `x[1]` returns you the first value
2. by filter `x[x < 0]` the expression inside the`[]` tell you if something holds the expression and the outside expression filters accroding to the result of the inner one.

Comment: Thank you very much @Domingo for the answer. I understood the conept.